# Nodemailer queryA EREFUSED localhost when using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I'm trying to send email to admin account whenever there's a new Order created in Firebase Database. I'm using Cloud Functions and Nodemailer for this, but I got below error:

> Error: queryA EREFUSED localhost
>       at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:213:19)

And this is the code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
admin.initializeApp();

/**
* Here we're using Gmail to send 
*/
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'mypass'
    }
});

exports.sendMail = functions.database.ref('/Order/{orderId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{
    const dest = 'destination@gmail.com';

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'Risal Fajar <noreply@bukakata.com>',
        to: dest,
        subject: 'I\'M A PICKLE!!!',
        html: `<p style="font-size: 16px;">Pickle Riiiiiiiiiiiiiiiick!!</p>
            <br />
            <img src="https://images.prod.meredith.com/product/fc8754735c8a9b4aebb786278e7265a5/1538025388228/l/rick-and-morty-pickle-rick-sticker" />
        `
    };

    // returning result
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
        console.log('Mail sent to ', dest);
    });
});
```

I don't know why the error showed **localhost** even though I've entered **smtp.gmail.com**

EDIT: I've added transport.verify() and this is the result

> { Error: queryA EREFUSED localhost
>       at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:213:19)
>     errno: 'EREFUSED',
>     code: 'EDNS',
>     syscall: 'queryA',
>     hostname: 'localhost',
>     command: 'CONN' }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FIXED IT

I fixed it by changing the transporter configuration (change service name) to:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'mypass'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the document: https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/

The gmail has another problem, but about this problem, same as I,
I got this Error:

> Error: { Error: queryA EREFUSED smtp.163.com
>       at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:199:19)

But when I try to run the same code at my mobile  using termux, it works,  maybe the free smtp services was so bad.

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer doesn't work for you, you can also try to check your DNS configuration and ensure a nslookup on the hostname works well.

Run:

```
nslookup 'hostname'
```

If this results in error go to your network parameters and change your current DNS to 8.8.8.8 and try again to if the error persists.
.Or run directly:

```
nslookup 'hostname' 8.8.8.8
```

Additionally if the error happens only in your Cloud/ Docker container or VM ensure the nameserver configuration is correct.

Note: I had this error because work wifi's primary DNS wasn't resolving 'smtp.office3.com' but the secondary did and it seems nodemailer has no process in place to resolve the hostname using secondary DNS or entry in the OS host. You can read more about how to fix is error in the Nodemailer faq [here](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#i-have-issues-with-dns--hosts-file).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a nodemailer old-version, maybe you need to update to a new one.

```
{
    "code": "EDNS",
    "syscall": "queryA",
    "hostname": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "command": "CONN"
}
```

Use dependency manager that you need ( npm, yarn, etc )

```
npm update nodemailer
```

Here, you can read more info about this error [nodemailer issue](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1493)